# send post variables to my Api

Tags: ios, swift, api

I am trying to send post parameters to my API, it gets 4 variables :

- `labelled`
- `id_produit`
- `id_magasin`
- `Prix`

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func AddProduct(sender: AnyObject) {


    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://vps43623.ovh.net/yamoinscher/api/products/create_product");let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    // Compose a query string
    let postString = "id=123456789&libelle=Florida&id_magasin=1&prix=1500";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // print out response object
        print("response = \(response)")

        // Print out response body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")


        }
    task.resume()

    }
```

And when I execute this code I get this response:

```
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fadeaf532a0> { URL: http://vps43623.ovh.net/yamoinscher/api/products/create_product } { status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 0;
"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
Date = "Thu, 28 Apr 2016 09:15:09 GMT";
"MS-Author-Via" = DAV;
Server = nginx;
"X-Powered-By" = PleskLin;
} })

responseString = Optional()
```

The console tells me that there is no variables sent to the api. Can any one help me please?

Comment: Status code response is 200. Are you sure you are expecting data?

Comment: What are you expecting back. And you are print response not the request which shows you that what variable sent to server. Response status code is 200 which means everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func AddProduct(sender: AnyObject) {


        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://vps43623.ovh.net/yamoinscher/api/products/create_product");let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
        // Compose a query string
        let postString = "id=123456789&libelle=Florida&id_magasin=1&prix=1500";
        let postLength = String(postData.length)

        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

            data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // print out response object
            print("response = \(response)")

            // Print out response body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")


            }
        task.resume()

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is in your `data` object. so, convert that data in approriate response format. Ask your web service provider that your response format is `string`, if yes then your code seems to be right but if your response is in `json format` then you should convert your data in `json object` with `jsonserialization`. so check this, because your status code is 200 means ok. so,there is no problem in code i think except response serialization. Try to convert data in json or try to convert it in string with different reading option which one is appropriate.

hope this will help :)